# SVG to mesh convertion troubleshooting

Tags: svg

I am importing a church plan from Adobe Illustrator / inkscape in svg.
I want to convert it into Mesh to fill the walls.

[image]

I converted it into a mesh

[image]

I want to fill the walls in edit mode but without success (Alt F)
(Not All the vertex seems to be connected)

[image]

[image]

Comment: of course you have no success, if you select all the vertices like that, blender pretty much confused by what you want, try to select 1 closed part of the wall at the time and press alt+F to fill it and then try another piece of enclosed wall... also try to merge by distance before fill

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @MikoCG  I tried a part of the plan (see my update)  without success. Fill doesnt work

Comment: I see a lot of black edges, that means disconnected vertices, did you try to merge? Can you share it?

Comment: @mqbaka mqbaka I tried a part of the plan (see my update) without success. Fill doesnt work

Comment: @MikoCG
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Enad2iFMZAA85ZBf3e3K9xuVyb80Ncgj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all your vertices, (not by mouse), press A to select all vertices
[image]

Every single line have to be orange, you can check that you selected all down here:
[image]

Now press M and select **By distance**

Now Alt+F works and F works as well...
[image]As I said you have to merge vertices because they are disconnected, that is normal for curves because some curves may not be actually enclosed.

Btw you can now select all of them at once and press Alt+F to fill all the walls at once